# print data in onchange

Tags: php, jquery

I want to print the data of one line of the DB, when varying the value of the select statement.

This is form

```
<div id=\"sendric\">
    <form name=\"form_sendrich\" id=\"form_sendric\" method=\"post\" action=\"inc/assegna_cs.inc.php\">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><i>&nbsp;Assegnazione squadra intervento</i></legend>

     <b><br/>
       <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Scegli la squadra pi&ugrave; vicina al luogo dell'intervento. Vedi mappa</span>
        <br/><br/>
        Squadra <select id=\"sel_cs\">");
                $i=0;
                while($i<$contcs){
                    print("<option name=\"id_cs\" value=\"".$tabcaposquadra[$i]['id']."\">".$tabcaposquadra[$i]['sede']."</option>");
                    $i++;
                }
        print("</select>
        <div id=\"datisquadra\"></div>   
        <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$idrich."\">
        <input type=\"submit\" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

this is JS with Jquery, which arises from the value of the select and send to the php page

```
    // Visualizzazione dati sull'onchange della select (delle squadre presenti)
$("#sel_cs").onchange(function(){
     var valueID=$("#sel_cs").val();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/vedisquadra.inc.php",
        data: "id_cs="+valueID,
        success: function(msg){
                     $("#datisquadra").html(msg);
             },
        error: function(msg){
                 $("#datisquadra").html(msg);
             },
        beforeSend:function(){
                     $("#datisquadra").html("<img hspace='84' src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...'  width='32' height='32'>");
             }
     });
});
```

this is script php to print data in asincrono, i do not think there are problems with this page

```
$id_ut=$_POST['id_cs'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `utenti` WHERE `id`=".$id_ut;//query nel db 
 $dati=mysql_query($sql);
 if (!$dati) {
    echo "Query non eseguita correttamente sul DB($sql): ".mysql_error();
    exit;
 }
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($dati, MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $cs_nome=$row['nome'];
 $cs_cognome=$row['cognome'];
 $cs_mail=$row['mail'];
 $cs_sede=$row['sede'];
 $cs_tool=$row['attrezzature'];


$msg="<br/>
    <b>Caposquadra: </b>".$cs_nome." ".$cs_cognome."<br/>
    <b>E-mail: </b>".$cs_mail."<br/>
    <b>Sede: </b>.".$cs_sede."</br>
    <b>Attrezzatura: </b>".$cs_tool;

echo $msg;
```

Comment: What's wrong ? What is the problem ? Where is the error ?

Comment: I think you will be best if you migrate your post to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't print, because the function jquery not called